# Spring/Hibernate. Manipulating entity reference a broken FK (intended)

Tags: hibernate, spring-data-jpa

Here's a case which I'm trying to handle?

Have two entities:

```
class Record {...}

class LogEntry {
   @JoinColumn
   @ManyToOne
   private Record record;
}
```

Having the long story short, I'm not declaring a FK constraint in the DB, thus removing `Record` when  `LogEntry` has a reference to it is expected.

When a read occurs by `repo.findAll()` an exception is thrown, which states that a `Record` by given id is absent.

Question is - is there a way to manipulate/configure this behavior? For example to create an empty `Record` object or etc?

note: setting to LAZY load isn't what I am looking for.
Also setting the entity in `LogEntry' to UUID is my 'plan B'.

Comment: Can the entity references be deleted by another system or is there another reason you cannot adjust the delete to do what you want after deleting the reference?

Comment: you want to have data in LogEntry table even if there is no entry for that Record? can you introduce soft_delet i.e. having a column in Record table such as is_deleted and your application checks this column. Deleting data from table is bad

Comment: "Can the entity references be deleted by another system" more or less so. The entity can be (and from what I imagine, it probably will) deleted by another system, and attaching cascades or restrictions (or even validations, which will interfere) is not an option. And I want the `LogEntry` to exist and be readable (giving a null or other behavior on broken FKs).

Comment: "you want to have data in LogEntry table even if there is no entry for that Record? ". That's the idea. `Record` gets deleted, but `LogEntry` remains and fetching it by means of Spring's `CrudRepository.findAll` will not fail on a broken FK. Having the soft deletes will require more effort that is needed for `plan B`, so also not an option.

Comment: The only thing I can think about are Hibernate Interceptors, but I can't give an example for this specific case. Maybe you can figure something out when you read into it.

Comment: Thanks. I debugged the flow of how hibernate makes the `findAll` and how it treats child elements, and went with `plan B` (no solution which would actually be fitting).